# How do I write this sentence in reported speech?

Tags: reported-speech

Jason doesn't like reading so he won't study literature .

How will it go ?

Will it be :
He said Jason didn't like reading so he won't study literature .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think it would depend who is reporting. The sentence you currently have, is someone reporting on another person who stated something about Jason. I.e.

> Tim about Stu: He said Jason didn't like reading, so he won't study literature.

However, I think you want it to be from Stu's point of view I.e.

> Stu about Jason:
>
> > Jason said he didn't like reading, so he won't study literature.
>
> Or
>
> > He said he didn't like reading, so he won't study literature.